# How is a relation defined from a structure and a formula?

Tags: logic

A structure maps a relation symbol to a relation over the domain set of the structure. So a structure maps a formula (consisting of relation symbols and other symbols) into a relation over the domain set of the structure.

Consider a structure $A$ and a formula $ϕ$ whose free variables are among $v_1 , . . . , v_k$ .
Then we can construct a $k$-ary relation on the domain set of $A$
$\{(a_1 , . . . , a_k)   | \models_A ϕ [a_1 , . . . , a_k ] \}$. (See Enderton's page 90)

Do they create  the same relations from a structure and a formula, by the definition of satisfaction?

Comment: Well, have you tried seeing what the definitions say each relation is?

Comment: I have but am confused

Comment: We have relation *symbols* of the language: if $R_n$ us an $n$-ary rel symbol, its interpretation in $A$ is a subset of $A \times \ldots \times A$ and exactly: $(a_1, \ldots a_n) \in R_n^A \text { iff } A \vDash R [a_1, \ldots, a_n]$

Comment: In the same way, a formula $\phi$ with $n$ free vars "identifies" a relation $R_{\phi}$ on $A$.